# Хостер меняет заголовки письма

Tags: email, php

Почему хостер меняет заголовки письма, а именно поле от кого. Я отправляю письмо через метод mail. Изначально поле from в коде задано на: $from = "heliogracie@mail.ru";
А оно при просмотре на почте это имя меняется на $from = "heliogracie@zeta.beget.ru". Хостер Beget. Проверял и на Google и в Mail.ru, одно и то же.

```
$to = "ivan@gmail.com";
$from = "heliogracie@mail.ru";
$successPage = "index.html";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = 'Заявка с сайта;
$phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber'];

$name = stripslashes($name);
$phoneNumber = stripslashes($phoneNumber);
$message = "Имя: $name <br /> Номер: $phoneNumber";
$headers = array
(
    'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";',
    'From: ' . $from,
    'Reply-To: ' . $from,
    'Return-Path: ' . $from,
);

if (empty($phoneNumber) || empty($name)){
    print "Поля не должны быть пустыми.<br>Пожалуйста заполните все поля.";
}
else {
    mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
    header("Location: $successPage");
}
```

Comment: @skyboy, это нормальная практика, связанная с тем, что хостер не хочет подписывать письма чужим сервисом. В настройках хостера должен задаваться исходящий адрес.

Comment: Так вроде бы это настройка относится в общем ко всем сайтам расположенным под моей учеткой на хостинге. А что если, я хочу для каждого сайта указать разный email адрес.

Comment: @skyboy, точно не помню, но вроде бы нужно еще, как минимум, в заголовки внести "Message-ID", не плохо бы "Date" и "MIME-Version". Если не поможет, то я бы попробовал добавить "X-Mailer", может тогда, с оглядкой на программу сгенерировавшую сообщение, заголовки будут идти "как есть".

----------

P.S. Вот еще, чтоб разогнать скуку, почитайте [RFC 5322][1] ;)

   [1]:http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.6.4